# Алгоритм фасетной фильтрации

Tags: алгоритм

Есть категории:

```
1. яблоки
2. апельсины
3. дыня
```

Со своими параметрами:

```
1. Яблоки
   Цвет - красный
   Форма - круглая
2. Апельсины
   Форма - круглая
   Цвет - желтый
3. Дыня
   Форма - овальная
   Цвет - желтый
```

Задача.
Отфильтровать категории относительно фильтров с возможностью множественного выбора с блокировкой неподходящих фильтров.

Например. Я выбираю яблоки. Мне становятся доступны такие фильтры, как форма круглая и цвет красный. Форма овальная и цвет желтый блокируются. Если к яблокам добавить категорию "дыня", то данные фильтры разблокируются.

Если изначально выбрать только цвет желтый, категория "яблоки" должна заблокироваться. Точно также и с формой.

Как корректно составить алгоритм фильтрации с множественным выбором, где каждый выбор фильтра влияет на доступность следующих.

**UPDATE**

Данные критерии представлены в виде чекбоксов на странице. Если фильтр не подходит, то он дизейблится:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="column">
    <div>Категория</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"/> Яблоко</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"/> Апельсин</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"/> Дыня</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>Цвет</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"/> Красный</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"/> Желтый</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>Форма</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"/> Круглая</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"/> Овальная</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE #2**

Пример фасетной фильтрации можно хорошо посмотреть на [яндекс маркете](https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--protsessory-cpu/55330/list?text=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80&hid=91019&rt=9&was_redir=1&srnum=521&rs=eJwzWsRoNJeRaxYjFy9H43FWASYJBlXNtkxbILcLyGUEcq8a59px8XF0A7kMEm-ZVNdUSzgApX8A-axA6Uv3ju0HcvcBuRxA7pOdz_YDVT_62cghwCzBqOq7YwtIeuNRVgFOoLTN0z8g7uczrALsQO5S2xsg1UfbW5kFWID8qVlHQfxjID6bBLPq-f6L-wMYAbYzMMg%2C&local-offers-first=0), где чекбоксы блокируются в зависимости от выбранной категории

**UPDATE #3**

все данные хранятся на клиенте в json, который и будет фильтроваться:

```
{
  "categories": {
    "apple": {
      "color": "red",
      "form": "round"
    },
    "orange": {
      "color": "yellow",
      "form": "round"
    },
    "melon": {
      "color": "yellow",
      "form": "oval"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Что то сами пробовали делать? Вам алгоритм надо или UI? Что значит блокируются? Блокируются где?

Comment: обновил вопрос. Нужен алгоритм. яп не принципиален, даже можно словами описать, чтобы просто понять, как данная фильтрация должна работать.

Comment: ну у вас есть фильтр и есть данные, так? Отфильтруйте данные, из полученных результатов посчитайте категории и подкатегории - они должны быть разрешены, остальное - отключено

Comment: Вы, кстати, не уточнили, у вас данные в памяти или в бд? Если бд, то какой?

Comment: Используется postgresql

Comment: Ну то есть вам надо написать запрос в бд, где на входе отмеченные фильтры, на выходе категории с флагом доступности (чтобы знать, какая категория доступна, какая нет), верно?

Comment: Нет. Фильтрация должна происходить без помощи сервера. По поводу фильтров ещё нужно учесть тот факт, что я могу выбирать несколько типов, т.е. несколько цветов, форм или категорий. Например, я выбрал желтый цвет => дизейблятся яблоки, но не красный цвет. Если я выбрал овальную форму, то дизейблятся яблоки, апельсины и красный цвет.

Comment: `Фильтрация должна происходить без помощи сервера` как вы планируете фильровать данные без сервера?

Comment: сервер при загрузке страницы отдает json, который содержит в себе все данные. Далее на клиенте при фильтрации он должен парсится

Comment: так у вас всё таки данные в памяти, а не в БД. Покажите пример такого json

Comment: относительно вопроса такая https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=6b6e17b06ccb4a928197e29959b961d1

Comment: В вопрос, добавляйте все в вопрос

Comment: добавил в вопрос